# Перемещение маркера на карте Android

Tags: android, карты, openstreetmap

Есть карта (osmdroid, хотя возможности с гугл/яндекс примерно одинаковы, наверно). На ней необходимо отображать движение транспорта. Есть ли какой-нибудь метод, чтобы перемещать маркер по карте? Гугл предлагает только удаление и добавление по новому. Не думаю, что такой вариант оптимальный.

Comment: увы и ах, но это так...

Comment: Взгляните, например, на это приложение. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.spb.spbtransport.ru
Всё, увы, очень печально.

Comment: судя по документации, можно, с помощью **marker.setDraggable(true)**